# Query on bigquery which is consuming lot of time

Tags: google-bigquery

I just started with bigquery but worried about the best practices as i just fired a query to get the results but it tooks lot of time than expected one, below snap has the query which fired.

[image]

Can some one guide me to make it fast over the big query or we dont have the mechanism to make it fast

Comment: You need to provide more details and please, copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

As a general advise, I would strongly recommend that you go over the [Query Performance best practices documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview). There, you will be able to find plenty of information on how to optimize performance on BigQuery from several perspectives (I/O, shuffling, specific query patterns...). Also, this other page on [how to troubleshoot BQ errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors) can be useful when you come across specific job errors, and also contains some best practices to deal with them. You might be interested in [estimating the costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs) (and also the amount of data that will be processed, and therefore estimating how complex a query really is) by using dry runs, too. Finally, you can have a look at the [Query Plan](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) in order to have a better understanding of how is the query execution going.

Regarding your specific use case, let me provide a couple of tips:

- Now that you are starting with BigQuery, begin with Standard SQL rather than Legacy SQL (I see that you are using Legacy SQL by the way you are calling tables, using the `[project:dataset.table]` format). Standard SQL is the recommended language to use with BigQuery, and although there might not be significant performance differences, there are some [advantages of using Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#comparison_of_legacy_and_standard_sql). You can [toggle the SQL language in use](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) through any of the methods presented in the documentation.
- You should [optimize your JOIN patterns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns) by placing the largest tables first (i.e. on the left-side of the JOIN operation).

---

Finally, I would like to share some tips on how to better work with Stack Overflow:

- *Do not share data you do not want other users to know.* For example, Project IDs or dataset names should ideally not be shared. Therefore, it is recommended that you obfuscate that data before sharing any query or similar. In this case, you are using public datasets, but if you are using your own, feel free to use placeholders instead.
- *Share the code instead of screenshots.* This way, the community can work in your question better, by being able to copy extracts without having to type it manually.
- *Be as specific as you can.* Investigate on your own, try to solve your issue, and then, if you need help from the Stack Overflow community, be as specific as you can regarding your issue. It will help us narrow down the solution and be able to help you the best way possible.
- *Visit the Help Center.* There you will be able to find plenty of information on [how to improve your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you get better answers for them.

Comment: Thanks @dsesto for your response!